# Why is my WiFi disabled in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I'm using ubuntu 18.04, and sometimes wifi will be disabled and display a blank page in network settings. I've tried

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

and

```
$ nmcli device
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION      
wlp3s0           wifi      unavailable  --
```

and

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       .
       .
       .
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       .
       .
       .
```

and

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlp3s0
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

and

```
$ rfkill list all
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

I'm trying to reinstall fireware-realtek and several other drivers manually:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

But nothing changes. When I run a wlp3s0 scan...

```
$ sudo iwlist wlp3s0 scan | grep ESSID
```

I get the following:

```
 wlp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning: Network is down
```

So I try to turn it on...

```
$ sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
$ sudo ip link set wlp3s0 up
```

And get the error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error
```

So the only way that I can access the wifi is reboot.

Comment: There is no need to reinstall a Realtek driver; your wireless is an Atheros. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubutnu.

Comment: i suggest to run # sudo iw reg set US ,then # sudo echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N msi=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf , also check the power management via # sudo iwconfig wlan0  .

Comment: @desertangels Its not work for me.

Comment: @chili555 thanks, I add the result and as you see  that command give the same result when wifi is connected

Comment: Take step and try to change option [ifupdown]
managed=true in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Comment: Please run: `dmesg | grep -e ath -e wlp` and pste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Gs3DV348Qf/

Comment: @desertangels nothing changed

Comment: That is a *lot* of errors and failures! Is this a dual boot? Does the wireless work properly in Windows? If you try a live session USB or DVD for Ubuntu 19.04 or 19.10, are the symptoms the same?

Comment: @chili555 yes, it happened in windows 10 Hardly ever and after restart, windows repair itself and for a long time I dont have any problem. I try ubuntu 19.10 live for a day but I dont have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem today after updating a week or so ago then putting my laptop away for a while.

Pulled out my laptop and wifi wasn't working.  Same outputs for the same commands.

If you run the software updater again it should fix your problem (which is annoying if you only have wifi).

If you can, connect to ethernet to get this done.  If not, plug your phone into your pc and enable USB tethering (if your phone has the option).

Running the software updater whilst connected via USB tethering fixed this problem for me.

It seems the last update invalidated the drivers for the wifi cards?  I'm not sure.

Comment: Running software updater or `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade` don't work for me.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem and I read infinite Answer and questions. But the solution is very very easy, if you really are experimenting a WiFi networking hard blocking.

Here the solution:

1. First check with

   ```
   sudo lshw -class network
   ```

   a response like that (may changes but it is important that you see the wi-fi adpater):

   ```
   *-network DISABLED
          description: Wireless interface
          product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
          vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
          physical id: 0
   ```
2. Turn off your laptop and remove physically the battery pack.
3. After a while reinsert the battery and the power supply.
   When you enter in Ubuntu again in network settings you can see that is possible to set your WiFi.

Comment: Removing battery and reinserting it, is same as rebooting the system. I don't how it worked and made the WiFi adaptor to work.